# Prove that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise, but not in measure in $[-1,1].$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x) = n^{3/2}xe^{-nx^2}.$ Prove that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise, but not in measure in $[-1,1].$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = n^{3/2}xe^{-nx^2} = 0,$ so that would prove that $f_n$ converges pointwise.

Based in the question [Let $f_n(x)=xne^{-nx}$ for all $x \ge 0$ and $n \ge 1$. Show that $(f_n)$ converges to zero on $[0, \infty)$ pointwise but not uniformly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045744/let-f-nx-xne-nx-for-all-x-ge-0-and-n-ge-1-show-that-f-n-conver) , I first tried to see if  $f_n(x) = n^{3/2}xe^{-nx^2}$ converges uniformly, by doing

$$ \int_0^{1/n} f_n(x)dx = \int_0^{1/n} n^{3/2}xe^{-nx^2}dx = -\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}(e^{-1/n}-1).$$ For $n=1,$ $-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}(e^{-1/n}-1)=-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{e}-1)>0.$ Does this really prove that the convergence is not uniform?

Mainly, does this helps me to prove that there is no convergence in measure?

Thanks

Comment: Convergence pointwise (or almost everywhere) on a finite measure space implies convergence in measure, so what you are trying to prove is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that convergence in measure to some function $f$ means that for each $\epsilon  > 0$, we have $$\mu\{x : |f(x) - f_n(x)| > \epsilon\} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0.$$

It actually is the case that this function *does* converge to $0$ in measure.  Fix $\delta > 0$, and consider the set $S_\delta = [-1, -\delta]\cup[\delta,1].$  Then for any $x \in S_\delta$, we have $$|f_n(x)| \leq n^{3/2} e^{-n \delta}.$$

As $n$ goes to infinity, this goes to zero for any $\delta$.  Thus, we have $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mu\{x : |f_n(x)| > \epsilon\} \leq 2\delta$$ for each $\delta$.  Taking $\delta \downarrow 0$ completes the proof.

---

It looks like maybe what you're looking for is that it doesn't converge in $L^1$.  This is what the other answer shows.

On a space of finite measure---like $[-1,1]$ for instance---uniform convergence implies convergence in $L^1$.  Convergence in measure is a different notion entirely.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-1}^1 |f_n(x)|\,dx=\int_{-1}^1n^{3/2}|x|
e^{-nx^2}\,dx=\sqrt n\int_{-\sqrt n}
^{\sqrt n}|y| e^{-y}\,dy\to\infty$$
as $n\to\infty$. Therefore $(f_n)$ does not tend to zero in $L^1$ norm.